# Crash when setting text to a custom table cell label

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, uilabel

My app crashes when I want to set the text of the label belonging to a table cell. My code snippet is as follows:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) 
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    [cell autorelease];

    CGRect splitMethodLabelRect = CGRectMake(160, 6, 50, 30); 
    UILabel *splitMethodLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:splitMethodLabelRect]; 
    splitMethodLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft; 
    splitMethodLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13]; 
    splitMethodLabel.tag = kSplitMethodTag;
    [cell.contentView addSubview: splitMethodLabel]; 
    [splitMethodLabel release];

}

UILabel *splitMethodName = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:kSplitMethodTag]; 

//app crashes at this point
splitMethodName.text = @"Test";
```

The issue seems to be at the point when I am setting the text. 
Stacktrace below:

```
2011-04-21 15:11:10.820 BillSplitter[3021:707] -[UITableViewCellContentView setText:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x18a680
2011-04-21 15:11:10.829 BillSplitter[3021:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewCellContentView setText:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x18a680'
```

Any advise on this is greatly appreciated!

Zhen

Comment: It's always a good idea to post the stacktrace :)

Comment: @Zhen: Change the *tag* value to something else and check if it crashes still.

Comment: @Simon, yes you are right. I assigned 0 to the tag value which crashes the app. I changed the value to 1 and it is working fine now. Thanks alot for your help!

Comment: @Simon +1 for your comment, which you should post as an answer so others can find it in the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that the *tag* value you've set to *splitMethodLabel* could be causing the problem.
`Just change the tag value to something else and check if it crashes still.`

Answer (score 2):

Ah the problem is: you are adding your own label to the cell as subview, but there is not a property given which references splitMethodName. The label is in the view hierarchy of the cell but you don't have a reference to access it.

You could fix this by subclassing UITableViewCell and add your label as a property. Use your custom class then. Override initWithStyle, pass the parameters to super, then create you label, add as subview AND assign to your property.